# How do I pull from a Docker registry only when required, or what does the word "latest" even mean?

Tags: docker, docker-in-docker

I'm using Gitlab-CI to build some Docker images in a docker-in-docker image. This is significant only because every build uses a new docker-in-docker environment with an empty Docker cache. It is possible to cache the cache in Gitlab and restore it later, but that does not appear safe--someone on the Web did it--but that does not seem safe.

I have a Docker registry in Nexus I have used successfully for pulling and pushing.

I have also set up saving images into Gitlab-ci's cache with `docker save` and loading from cache with `docker load`.

With either pulling from the registry *or* loading from the Gitlab-CI cache, I can then run `docker build --cache-from ...` and Docker will build incrementally, not rebuilding any layers of images that have not changed.

All built images get the `latest` tag.

The part that does not work is this: If I load an image from the Gitlab-CI cache, then pull from the registry, the image from the registry is *always* used as the from Docker's point-of-view, even if it is weeks older than the one loaded from cache. This seems like defective behavior--to say the least, it is highly unexpected and undocumented as far as I can tell.

How can I tell Docker to:
1) use the later latest as the latest (alternatives without the `latest` tag are a possibility), and
2) only download layers that have changed since what was loaded into Docker's cache?

That's 2 questions, but I'm hoping they have the same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, if you mean `yourimage:latest`, the `latest` means nothing because it is only a convention and not a guarantee that you are really pulling the literally latest (newest) image.

If you load an image `yourimage:latest` from local and afterwards you pull the same named image from a registry (`yourimage:latest`) the last one will be the timely `latest`. Because it is different from the first one even if the first one would be the timely newer one. If it has another fingerprint, it will be overwritten.